# What does it mean for a two dimensional feature vector to have unit variances?

Tags: bayesian, variance

What does it mean for a two dimensional feature vector to have unit variances?

This is related to a Bayesian Discriminant Function problem.

For example, the feature vector for one of the classes has a mean of (3, 0) and unit variances.  Does that mean $\sigma^2$ is (1, 1)?  Is it ($\sqrt{2}/2$, $\sqrt{2}/2$)?

Comment: It means the variance of each individual feature is one.